# Expected type mismatch haskell

Tags: haskell, types, try-catch

I'm using the following haskell code to catch error while 'read' in int using getLine. I'm having a type mismatch error when CheckInt function is called. Please let me know where should I modify the type.

```
import System.Exit 
import Control.Exception
funSeq n = do
     if (n<4) then 1 else  floor $ (fromIntegral (funSeq (n-1) + funSeq (n-2))) * ((fromIntegral.funSeq) (n-3) / (fromIntegral.funSeq) (n-4))


myFunc ('N':'T':'H':' ': restOfString) = do
   checkInt restOfString
   let num = (read restOfString :: Int)
   if (num < 0) then showError else print (funSeq (num))

main = do
 putStrLn "Enter the code: "
 code <- getLine
 myFunc code
 main 


checkInt :: String -> IO ()
checkInt str =  catch (seq (read str :: Int) $ return ()) showError

showError :: SomeException -> IO ()
showError _ =  do
    putStrLn("ERR")
    exitSuccess
```

Comment: When asking such questions, always __post the error__, pointing at the line.

Answer (score 2):

There may be other errors, but the following jumps out to me:

```
showError :: SomeException -> IO ()

myFunc ... = do
    ...
    if ... then showError else ...
```

Since `showError` is a function, you probably ought to give it an argument here.